# Modifying an old phone to draw less power?

Tags: resistors, integrated-circuit, gps, cellphone

I have a phone that I would like to install in my car as a GPS tracker, using the following guide: http://gizmodo.com/5691724/how-to-track-your-vehicle-on-the-cheap

I'd like to keep it hardwired to the car if possible.  The requirements:

- The phone needs to stay on at all times
- The phone needs to be drawing minimal power from the battery
- The phone needs to have the screen and keypad removed to reduce its size

Would removing unnecessary hardware reduce the power draw of the phone?  What can I do to minimize the chance of killing my battery with this thing?

Comment: How much is "minimal power"?

Answer (score 4):

You'll need the phone transmitter to be constantly on and that's what draws the main share of power. You still can remove stuff like LEDs and backlight to save a bit.

Regarding not killing your battery - you have to choose the charger to be power efficient. Those can vary in terms of quality and efficiency quite broadly. Then you have to measure the amount of current the setup draws and depending on how frequently you drive your car it might be no problem after all. Typical car battery capacity is around 100 amp-hours, if your setup draws, say 100mA @ 12V and you drive every day, you should be ok.